# How to ignore zero value in struct in Google Datastore for Golang?

Tags: go, google-apps, google-cloud-datastore

I am trying to use Google Datastore to store data by Go. Since the `EndDate` is optional field, and don't want to store zero value in that field. If I make a pointer for time field, Google Datastore will send an error message - `datastore: unsupported struct field type: *time.Time`

How can I ignore zero value field in struct?

```
type Event struct {
    StartDate time.Time `datastore:"start_date,noindex" json:"startDate"`
    EndDate   time.Time `datastore:"end_date,noindex" json:"endDate"`
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default saving mechanism does not handle optional fields. A field is either saved all the time, or never. There is no such thing as "only save if it's value does not equal to something".

The "optionally saved property" is considered a custom behavior, a custom saving mechanism, and as such, it has to be implemented manually. Go's way to do this is to implement the [`PropertyLoadSaver`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/datastore/reference#PropertyLoadSaver) interface on your struct. Here I present 2 different methods to achieve that:

#### Manually saving fields

Here is an example how to do it by manually saving the fields (and excluding `EndDate` if it is the zero value):

```
type Event struct {
    StartDate time.Time `datastore:"start_date,noindex" json:"startDate"`
    EndDate   time.Time `datastore:"end_date,noindex" json:"endDate"`
}

func (e *Event) Save(c chan<- datastore.Property) error {
    defer close(c)
    // Always save StartDate:
    c <- datastore.Property{Name:"start_date", Value:e.StartDate, NoIndex: true}

    // Only save EndDate if not zero value:
    if !e.EndDate.IsZero() {
        c <- datastore.Property{Name:"end_date", Value:e.EndDate, NoIndex: true}
    }
    return nil
}

func (e *Event) Load(c chan<- datastore.Property) error {
    // No change required in loading, call default implementation:
    return datastore.LoadStruct(e, c)
}
```

#### With another struct

Here's another way using another struct. The `Load()` implementation is always the same, only `Save()` differs:

```
func (e *Event) Save(c chan<- datastore.Property) error {
    if !e.EndDate.IsZero() {
        // If EndDate is not zero, save as usual:
        return datastore.SaveStruct(e, c)
    }

    // Else we need a struct without the EndDate field:
    s := struct{ StartDate time.Time `datastore:"start_date,noindex"` }{e.StartDate}
    // Which now can be saved using the default saving mechanism:
    return datastore.SaveStruct(&s, c)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I just wonder how can I use that "save" function in my controller. Since Datastore has a method called "Put" which will save the item to datastore. Do I need to call that "save" function before calling "Put" function of Datastore?

Comment: @Kit The use of this `save()` method is implicit, you don't have to call it. You can save your entity as usual, e.g. with the `datastore.Put()`. The `Put()` function will check if the value you want to save implements `PropertyLoadSaver`, and if so, the implementation of the `Put()` method will call the `save()` method.

Comment: Thanks! It works. But need to change the interface a little bit (not channel) because the interface of that in datastore is https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/cloud/datastore#PropertyLoadSaver

Comment: @Kit Then it looks you're using the Cloud datastore which slightly differs from AppEngine Datastore. In my example I was showcasing AppEngine Datastore.

Answer (score 1):

Use omitempty in the field tags.
From the docs: https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/

> Struct values encode as JSON objects. Each exported struct field
>   becomes a member of the object unless
>
> - the field's tag is "-", or
> - the field is empty and its tag specifies the "omitempty" option.
>
> Field int `json:"myName,omitempty"`

Comment: The Datastore does not store entities as JSON, it does not use JSON marshaling/umarshaling. Changing the json value in the field tag has no effect on Datastore saving at all. Asker does not want to exclude the field _all the time_, he just wants to exclude it _if its run-time value_ is the zero value.